# Is there a command similar as MySQL's "set names" in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Mongodb use utf-8 in internal, how to set the output charset? Is there a command similar as MySQL's "set names"? I using c++ mongoclient.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure If the c++ driver behaves differently, but from what I know you'll always get a UTF-8 encoded result back. So if you want those data converted to another character set you need to perform it for yourself (don't know what ways you have with c++).

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB exclusively deals with UTF-8. You can't change either input or output character sets and character encodings. You will need to do that in your application, where you also need to make sure that every string you send to MongoDB is actually UTF-8. None of the drivers currently support anything else. It's not likely they will ever do either.